# Get a django queryset that includes data from 5 linked models

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have 5 models that are linked with foreign keys like this:

```
Section (Registration.section)
^ 1
|
v ∞
Registration < ∞ --- 1 > Event (Registration.event)
^ ∞
|
v 1
User (Registration.user, Profile.user)
^ 1
|
v 1
Profile
```

From these linked models, I am trying to display the data in a table like this:

```
| ID             | Other Profile fields    | Section1                     | Section2                    | SectionN |
|----------------|-------------------------|------------------------------|-----------------------------|----------|
| user1.username | eg. user1.profile.grade | Registration.objects.get(    | Registration.objects.get(   |
                                           |    section=Section1,         |   section=Section1,         |
                                           |    user=user1   |   user=user1   |
                                           | ).event                      | ).event                     |
|----------------|-------------------------|------------------------------|-----------------------------|----------|
| user2.username | user2.profile.grade     | ...event                     |None (needs to handle this)  | 
|----------------|-------------------------|------------------------------|-----------------------------|----------|
| user3.username | user3.profile.grade     | None (needs to handle this)  |None (needs to handle this)  |          |
```

Where every user has a distinct row.  What I can't figure out how to do efficiently is get the Registration(s) for each Section.

I CAN do this by manually manipulating the data in python with dictionaries and loops etc, but this is so inefficient that my server times out before it can complete the process if the User list is too large.

What queryset structure to I need to create to be able to output the data like this in a template?

Each section will only have one registration object per user:

```
class Registration(models.Model):

    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    section = models.ForeignKey(section, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("event", "user", "section")
```

Answer (score 0):

In practice, I suggest that you do paging:

1. query only the first 100 users -> you have a list of userids.
2. `Registration.objects.filter(user__in=[1,42,...]).values_list()`
3. pair up the data (it may even come out of the database in the correct order).
4. Do this for the other related models.

This should be pretty fast. You don't want to see more than 100 users on a page anyway.

**Answering your question:**

You can try using values_list that will result in a single `join` SQL query on the DB if you do `Registration.objects.values_list('event__property', 'user__username', 'user__profile__grade')`. (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values)

and values_list does not produce Model objects so it will be faster.

If you need all the data together, the most robust solution though is to just do caching. Run a daily script with cron that does your table in the background and stores it in a table (via a `PickleField`), if that is an option. (Even if you need more up-to-date data, I would suggest a background process for heavy queries like this one, with a status flag in the db (key: input, status: processing or ready, data: PickleField).)

If there are a ton of users, even the `join`-ed DB query will be slow, using a relational database.
Your approach should be one of the fastest, since it is just 4-5 DB query + processing.